# Looping through Pandas Dataframe Columns to count values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a column with 14000+ rows and there is only two numbers in this column.

```
for i  in df['Yes/No']:
  
  if(i in "Yes"):
    y_counter += 1

  else:
    n_counter += 1
```

When I try this I get an equal 12/12 return for each counter. That is definitely not correct. How do I loop through and count the Yes and Nos?

Comment: `df['Yes/No'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```py
y_counter = (data['Yes/No'] == 'yes').sum()
n_counter = (data['Yes/No'] == 'no').sum()
```